# iOS Session Cookies are being returned with expiration

Tags: ios, session, cookies

Our web server guys (JSP) are setting session cookies on the server that appear to be showing up with a date of December 31st 2000 when viewed client side-via the Safari Inspector for iPhone Simulator. We were expecting the cookies to show up as "Session" cookies when we inspected them. Is this an issue with the Development Tool or is there something we are not doing properly on the server.  Note: the cookies do come across as NULL when viewed within iOS.